# Please suggest a test class to cover the below part of my code

Tags: failing-tests

```
PageReference p = new PageReference('/' + Case.SObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix() + '/e');
                Map<String, String> m = p.getParameters();
                m.putAll(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters());                       
                m.put('nooverride', '1');                       
                p.setRedirect(true);
                return p;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming above method is a part of controller class, you can call that method by creating a instance of a class inside a test method.

```
public with sharing class ControllerExample1{

    public ControllerExample1(){}

    public PageReference method1(){

    PageReference p = new PageReference('/' + Case.SObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix() + '/e');
    Map<String, String> m = p.getParameters();
    m.putAll(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters());                       
    m.put('nooverride', '1');                       
    p.setRedirect(true);
    return p;
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest 
private class ControllerExampleTestClass {
    static testMethod void validateStackExchange1() {
       ControllerExample1 ctrl= new ControllerExample1();
       ctrl.method1();
       // System.assert statements goes here..
    }
}
```

Check [Testing Custom Controllers and Controller Extensions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_error_handling.htm)

Comment: Hi Devendra,
How do I cover this part of my code

Comment: PageReference p = new PageReference('/' + Case.SObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix() + '/e');
    Map<String, String> m = p.getParameters();
    m.putAll(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters());                       
    m.put('nooverride', '1');                       
    p.setRedirect(true);
    return p;